# Two divs in line where first div contains some other div

Tags: html, css

I would like to make some *content boxes*.

A number icon, then title

text text text text

Here is a  [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/oe19ezz9/)

```
<div class="icon_title_wrapper">
    <div class="icon_number_container">
        <div class="icon_number_number">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon_title_title">THIS IS TITLE</div>
</div>
```

I would like to have two divs in line (icon and title)

but icon div is kind of complex because I needed to make the number vertically and horizontally centered....  and now that number is messing with title div...

Can you guys help me?

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oe19ezz9/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.icon_number_container{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  background-color: #45484c; 
  border-spacing:5px;
}

.icon_number_number{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon_title_title{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}
.icon_title_wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon_title_wrapper">
  <div class="icon_number_container">
    <div class="icon_number_number">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon_title_title">THIS IS TITLE</div>
</div>
as a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text
```

Comment: Why DownVote Comment Please

Comment: I didnt downvote... I just pressed the upper arrow... you need to edit something so I can give the up vote.. I dont know

Answer (score 2):

You have to set icon number container and title `display: inline-block`. And you will have to remove that `float` on your title div cause it messes up with content.

Try it in the snippet below:

```css
.icon_number_container{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    background-color: #45484c; 
    border-spacing:5px;
}

.icon_number_container, .icon_title_title{
    display:inline-block;
}

.icon_number_number{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 31px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon_title_wrapper">
    <div class="icon_number_container">
        <div class="icon_number_number">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon_title_title">THIS IS TITLE</div>
</div>
as a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oe19ezz9/6/) implementing `word-wrap` for long titles. You can try it and modify it however you want the number and title to be vertically aligned when the title is too long.

Comment: OP Wants > " I needed to make the number vertically and horizontally centered.... "

Comment: did you try the fiddle I added?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `float: right;` from `.icon_title_title`. And apply following css will work for you.

```
.icon_title_title {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oe19ezz9/3/)**

**Edit:**

To solve ugly icon issue you should use `display:inline-block;`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oe19ezz9/5/)**

Comment: Thanks. but now I get this ugly long number icon that follows the number of lines of title.. http://prntscr.com/9cfw7u

Comment: Thank you very much! One more thing, though: If I put the title in <strong> tags... then it moves below the icon....

Comment: Yes, yes. It is working, but only with <br> tag involved. If I resize the window, the title is always the same (3 lines) even though there is sometimes space for the title to be one line...